# Recommended sites to link to when you have an attachment

Tags: support, best-practices, attachment

I frequently post in the [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) topic.
Sometimes it is nice to be able to attach sourcecode of components that solve a particular issue.
Stack Overflow does not allow attachments outright for good reasons, you need to put a link to a storage site somewhere.

As we all know links break and storage expires.

**Which storage site would you recommend** to store a file attachment, so that my "`this component is downloadable here`" answer does not become useless because the link dies over time?

Answer (score 4):

If you have so much sourcecode that it can not fit into the post, *you or the OP is doing something wrong*.

Anyway, [Gist from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/) is a good idea in my opinion. GitHub is not going away in the next time (availability of the code) and has some nice features in there.